# Date Filter to return past 365 days starting last year

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I need help with a date filter that uses date column `DATE_REQUEST` to return data 365 days prior to today's date last year.

Today's date is `2023-04-20`, so I want it to start from `2022-04-20` and return data between `2022-04-19` until `2021-04-20`

Date is of type `TIMESTAMP` and uses UTC time zone.

```
SELECT 
    FLIGHT_MONTH,
    IATA_OD,
    SERV_DEP_COUNTRY,
    SERV_ARR_COUNTRY,
    SUM(max_quantity) AS PAX, 
    SUM(sum_price) AS FPPRICE
FROM (
    SELECT
        DATE_TRUNC(DATE(t.DATE_DEPARTURE), MONTH) AS FLIGHT_MONTH,
        t.id_pnr AS PNR,
CONCAT(t.IATA_CODE_SERVICE_DEP_CITY, "-", t.IATA_CODE_SERVICE_ARR_CITY) AS IATA_OD,
        t.DESC_SERVICE_DEP_COUNT AS SERV_DEP_COUNTRY,
        t.DESC_SERVICE_ARR_COUNT AS SERV_ARR_COUNTRY,
        MAX(t.ID_PAX_RANGE) max_quantity,
        SUM(t.FLIGHTPROVIDERPRICE) sum_price

FROM `DATA_TABLE` t

WHERE 
      DATE_REQUEST >= TIMESTAMP_SUB(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(), INTERVAL 750 DAY)

    GROUP BY  FLIGHT_MONTH, PNR, IATA_OD, SERV_DEP_COUNTRY, SERV_ARR_COUNTRY,  
) t

GROUP BY  FLIGHT_MONTH, IATA_OD, SERV_DEP_COUNTRY, SERV_ARR_COUNTRY
ORDER BY  FLIGHT_MONTH, IATA_OD, SERV_DEP_COUNTRY, SERV_ARR_COUNTRY
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

you can use below expressions in your query. you probably also have to supply timezone if the dates are in two different timezones.

```
SELECT 
   CURRENT_DATETIME("Australia/Melbourne") as current_datetime_ ,
   DATETIME_SUB(CURRENT_DATETIME(), INTERVAL 366 DAY) as period_1,
   DATETIME_SUB(DATETIME_SUB(CURRENT_DATETIME(), INTERVAL 366 DAY), INTERVAL 365 DAY) as period_2
FROM your_table 
WHERE DATE_REQUEST BETWEEN 
DATETIME_SUB(CURRENT_DATETIME(), INTERVAL 366 DAY) 
AND
DATETIME_SUB(DATETIME_SUB(CURRENT_DATETIME(), INTERVAL 366 DAY), INTERVAL 365 DAY)
```

Comment: I have updated my question with my SQL code. The SQL return no data when I added your code.

Comment: Hi there, can you please give sample input data your query is using?